# Strip Html Tags In Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Using ionic 3 I have fetched some data from wordpress api and am then displaying the same on app UI. Everything seems to work fine except the HTML tags included in the content. The html tags are printed too. I have referred to some resources that suggested the following code :-

```
`var app = angular.module('myHDApp', []);

    app.filter('removeHTMLTags', function() {

    return function(text) {

        return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';

};

});
```

I have implemented the above function in my .ts code but it does not seems to work for me as I still get the HTML tags in the content.

Comment: That looks like code for ionic v1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have found is for ionic v1. In ionic 3, you have to create a pipe first.

In your cli,

```
ionic g pipe removehtmltags
```

You can find your newly created pipe under src/pipes. Now in your **removehtmltags.ts**,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';    

@Pipe({
  name: 'removehtmltag',
})
export class RemovehtmltagPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(value: string) {
           if(value){
               var result = value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ""); //removing html tag using regex pattern
              return result;
           }
           else{}


  }
}
```

You can now use this pipe in your html files like this,

```
<p>{{yourData | removehtmltag}}</p>
```

Comment: also could you suggest a way if i want to add some tags as an exception to this?

Comment: coulb you be more precise? tags like what?

Comment: Tags like <br> or <pre> etc

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest solution:

```
removeHTMLInfo(value: string)
{  
    if (value)

        return value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, "");
}
```